# Can't install python3 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, package-management, python3

I fresh installed Ubuntu 18.04. I want to install python on it so I can run flask on it, but for some reason every time I run

```
sudo apt install python3-minimal
```

I keep getting these results:

```
ashoms@ashoms:~$ sudo apt install python3-minimal
[sudo] password for ashoms: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-minimal is already the newest version (3.6.5-3ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/53.4 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of update-manager:
 update-manager depends on policykit-1; however:
  Package policykit-1 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package update-manager (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk:
 ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk depends on update-manager; however:
  Package update-manager is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 update-manager
 ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: This seems like there were issues during the install.... apt tells you that python is already installed, but it then tries to finish up outstanding tasks (possibly from the install)

Comment: There are severe packages inconsistencies *and* for installing python3 in debian based systems, you install the package `python3` or similar name. If using kali, use something else.

Comment: Thanks a lot for responding, it's been driving me crazy, cant get any work done. But how can I solve the issue cause I have a lot to do and they all keep coming up with the same error.

Comment: If a new server, I would reinstall it. You are missing essential packages for system and package administration.

Comment: am using ubuntu 18.04 lts on hp655 64bit amd processor...

Comment: Reinstalling the whole thing isnt an option here please cause this the second time am installing the same OS in less than two days

Comment: Basically this is what's common between all the error message I get;

Comment: update-manager
 ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt -f install`  (--fix-broken)  Ubuntu comes with both python 2.7 (default python) and Python 3.6 (python3) installed

Comment: Python3 seems already installed.
To fix the problem indicated by `apt`: Have you tried installing policykit-1? `sudo apt install policykit-1`

Answer (score -1):

First try

```
sudo apt -f install
```

Then again try to install it. If the problem continues, then try these codes

1. `mkdir ~/junk && cd ~/junk`
2. `apt-get download python3.5-minimal`
3. `dpkg-deb -X $(ls pyth*) .`
4. `sudo cp -aiv usr/bin/python3.5 /usr/bin`
5. `sudo dpkg-reconfigure python3.5-minimal`

Use [this](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=245836) link for to make it more clear.